# How do I create an Ubuntu live usb using Debian?

Tags: ubuntu, iso-image, debian-lenny, usb-storage

I have Debian (Lenny) installation on a Dell Vostro v13. The laptop doesn't have a CD/DVD-ROM drive so the only way for me to install Ubuntu on it is via USB- unless I attach an external CD/DVD-ROM. How can I create an Ubuntu live USB on my Debian machine? Is UNetbootin my only option or is there another way? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I believe dd would also be a viable option:

```
dd if=________.iso of=/dev/sd_
```

Where 'if' is your input file and 'of' is your output file (ie device).

Comment: Have you tried this? It doesn't work on newer Ubuntu versions (the drive is not bootable).

Answer (score 1):

You can use tools like UNetbootin, usb-creator etc to do it. Or you could manually do it :

- Copy/Extract files from the ISO to the root dir of your USB Drive
- Set the boot flag for your usb ddevice(use gparted or cfdisk)
- run : `syslinux -sm /dev/your_usb_dev`
- Create syslinux.cfg file in usb root dir with content :
  include isolinux/isolinux.cfg

Comment: According to `man syslinux` there's no such option as `-m`. Very interesting though, I'll try it soon!

Answer (score 1):

As root, just:

```
cat the_ubuntu.iso > /dev/sdX
```

then

```
sync
```

… and voilà.

Comment: Or you can use dd. Will be faster.